# Akka vs Redis as system for reliable message delivery

Tags: java, redis, akka, message-queue

I am trying to figure out what solution to choose for message delivery system in java project. So far my findings concentrated on **redis message queue and akka persistence in java**.

**Case:**

System receives synchronous request from another component. After that system is responsible for passing request to asynchronous handler (worker) and get back ack when work will be done by worker. I thought about implementing message queue which will correspond to each request(task) or use akka persistence for this.

Assumptions:

- Tasks done by worker(s) are rather heavy.
- Workers failures have to be handled

**Findings:**

**Akka** persistence gives reliable message delivery with failure handling via akka-persistence. 
Personally I do not like the java code of akka, many instanceof,  casts etc but most things are covered under the hood.

**Redis** does offer publish/subscribe message queue but I would like more point to point communication with popping messages from queue.
With little help of commands leftPush(lpush) on producer side and rightPopLeftPush on the consumer side I am able to get mostly the needed solution.

And now the question is what You will use in such case ? Do you suggest any other solutions ? What are your expierience in case of reliability and scalability ?.

Answer (score 1):

Check out RabbitMQ and [Topic Exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html). RabbitMQ queues can be persistent and you can manualy ACK messages that you have processed (at least once delivery).

Comment: Thanks, ended up with using akka with at least one delivery pattern. So far so good and it's working without problems.